# Video streaming of the movie with blocked access

Tags: javascript, php, video

I made a small private site (16 people) with a movie player and database.
The idea is that the videos can only be played in the page player, but not directly from the link (domain / media / video.mp4). And I did it, but hosting imposes a limit on the weight of one movie by this way. In addition, I have to wait for the entire movie to download. I have searched many guides, but none match my expectations. What can I do?

My current code (simplified):

I blocked access via `.htaccess` in the media folder:

```
Order allow, deny
from all
```

Encode movie to base64:

```php
if ($file_location == 1) {
  $topic_komunikat = $topic;
  $file = $location;
  $h = fopen($file, 'rb');
  $c = fread($h, filesize($file));
  fclose($h);
  $film = getimagesize($file);
  $film = base64_encode($c);
}
```

and player:

```php
echo
  '<video
    width="500px"
    controls
    src="data: video / mp4; base64, '. $film.'"> The “video” tag is not supported by yourbrowser.
  </video>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved use case (if you are just interested in the usage vs building it on your own). Take a look - https://vidberrys.com/about. You can upload your videos, mark it private, create a private watch party with 16 people and watch the videos together while talking to each other, react to it and create reaction videos as well if you like!!